# Get duplicate values from mySQL using GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I want to get the count of p1 which r1 having

| R1 | P1 |
| --- | --- |
| RC1 | PC1 |
| RC1 | PC1 |
| RC2 | PC2 |
| RC1 | PC3 |
| RC1 | PC3 |

I want to get the result like bellow

| R1 | count(P1) |
| --- | --- |
| RC1 | 2 |
| RC2 | 1 |

Can anyone please help to write MySQL query to get this?

Answer (score 3):

Distinct can help to avoid duplicate values while counting.

distinct with count group by :

```
select R1, count(distinct P1) from test 
group by R1
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not produce duplicate using `group by` if the condition (table and query) are as below and it does not need distinct in this case:

> DISTINCT can be considered as a special case of GROUP BY ( SELECT
> DISTINCT c1 from t1 is the same as SELECT c1 from t1 GROUP BY c1 ) and
> the same restrictions apply so GROUP BY clause of SELECT DISTINCT can
> only include expressions or columns already selected

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  r1 varchar(10),
  p1 varchar(10) );

INSERT INTO `test` VALUES
('RC1','PC1'),
('RC1','PC1'),
('RC2','PC2'),
('RC1','PC3'),
('RC1','PC3');

SELECT  r1,count(p1) 
FROM test
GROUP BY r1;
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/48